# video streaming from firebase using media controller

Tags: android, firebase, video-streaming, android-videoview, mediacontroller

```
public class MessageFragent extends Fragment {


    private VideoView videoView;
    private Uri videoUrl;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message,container, false);


        videoView = v.findViewById(R.id.vviewVideo);
        videoUrl = Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/login-app-3bb2f.appspot.com/o/%E0%AC%9A%E0%AC%89%E0%AC%A0%E0%AC%BF%20%E0%AC%B0%E0%AC%BE%E0%AC%A4%E0%AC%BF%20--%20new%20odia%20comedy%20video%20--%20odia%20talking%20Tom%20video%20--%20Hasi%20hasi%20gadi%20jebe%20--%20odia%20jokes--.mp4?alt=media&token=4f74b5f7-5cfd-4338-936f-7b518bb9bc55");
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUrl);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        return v;
    }

}
```

my video is not streaming and is showing can't play the video file

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Request focus(); start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method to play the video -

```
videoView.start();
```

As done below -

```
videoView = v.findViewById(R.id.vviewVideo);
videoUrl = Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/login-app-3bb2f.appspot.com/o/%E0%AC%9A%E0%AC%89%E0%AC%A0%E0%AC%BF%20%E0%AC%B0%E0%AC%BE%E0%AC%A4%E0%AC%BF%20--%20new%20odia%20comedy%20video%20--%20odia%20talking%20Tom%20video%20--%20Hasi%20hasi%20gadi%20jebe%20--%20odia%20jokes--.mp4?alt=media&token=4f74b5f7-5cfd-4338-936f-7b518bb9bc55");
videoView.setVideoURI(videoUrl);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: I have tried all sorts of things...but still I m stuck....my file is MP4... And 31 mb...

Comment: No...but I don't know about it.. how to make it work

Comment: Do I need to add any dependencies...?

Comment: Sorry....guys to bother you..... It isn't working in simulator..but works fine in my phone when I imported my APK....can you tell me how to make it work in simulator????

Comment: Raj.. please check my other questions..n reply